# Access Subform: how to set Continuous Form view?

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in a `Single Form` view. In this form, I have a subform that is currently in `Datasheet` view. I would like to switch the subform view to `Continuous Form`.

The problem is that in `Property Sheet` of the subform I don't have the field `Default View`, like in the main form. So I don't know to do this change.

This is the `Property Sheet` of the main form. You can see that the `Default View` field is available.

[image]

This is the `Property Sheet` of the subform. As you see there is no `Default View` field.

[image]

Comment: You need to set it at the form itself, not the control which holds the subform.

Comment: Yep, open the subform in Design view, then you have the property.

Comment: Or click the Subform/Subreport, then click it *again* so you're on the form itself, as @KostasK. described.